# Could not create task ':path_provider_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig' during Flutter android gradle sync?

Tags: android, flutter

In flutter project during gradle sync in android module.
what I had tried:

```
Flutter clean
Flutter pub cache repair
gradlew clean and build
```

every code tried for clean and removing invalid caches.
Got stuck after many times of downloading different types of gradle version(approx. 20GB).
got error

```
Could not create task ':path_provider_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
this and base files have different roots: D:\myProject\build\path_provider_android and C:\Users\10\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_android-2.0.13\android.
```

my `pubspec.yml`

```
path_provider: ^2.0.9
```

project level Gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0-alpha09'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do the following process in order.
At least it did work for me

1. Run this command `flutter clean`
2. Then this `flutter pub cache repair`
3. If using Visual Studio Code, Restart it.
4. If using Android Studio, Invalidate Cache and Restart

> Also Make sure you are using Java 11 or newer